# remote request nginx with lua

Tags: nginx, lua

I was trying to make it works a lua code in my nginx.conf file, where I was trying to connect to another web application by proxy_pass and depending of the HTTP result render some resources.
Here´s my code

```
location /_auth {
    proxy_set_header  Accept-Encoding  "";
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/Welvi-rest;
}
location /server/ {
    content_by_lua "
        local res = ngx.location.capture('/_auth');
        ngx.print(res.status);
        if res.status ~= ngx.HTTP_OK then
            ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_FORBIDDEN)
        end
    ";
}
```

But I dont know why the web application server in 8080 is never invoked.

I read something related with issue that is because the headers that we need to add in lua, but I could not found a fix of this problem

Comment: Can you show the whole config? I suppose this location is just never entered. This style location: matches any query beginning with /server/ and continues searching, so regular expressions will be checked. This will be matched only if regular expressions don't find a match.

Comment: Thanks, looks like was something so stupid because the /_auth had not the / at the end.